# Convert .sdf to .bak

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-ce, backup

I'm trying to publish a webproject MVC3 .NET with binero.se. The problem is that my database file is .sdf. And binero wants a .bak file.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: `.sdf` is SQL Server **Compact Edition** - totally separate and vastly different from "real" SQL Server. I don't think there's any quick'n'easy way to "convert" this to a full-blown SQL Server `.mdf` or `.bak` file, sorry....

Answer (score 4):

`.sdf` is the file format for SQL Server **Compact Edition** and that's quite a different beast from "real" SQL Server. `.bak` is the database backup format for a full-blown SQL Server.

The way to get from `.sdf` to `.bak` would be:

- create a temporary database in a "full" SQL Server (Express, Standard, Enterprise) with the name of the `.sdf` file
- using a tool like [SQL Server Compacst data and schema scripting](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/), export your table structure and data from the SQL Server CE file into "full" SQL Server
- once you've created all tables and other DB objects and inserted all your data into the "full" SQL Server database, create a backup of that database to get your `.bak` file

Comment: ok but I cant open the .sdf file at all in SQL server 2008. So the problem is that I can't import my tables from the .sdf file to SQL.

Comment: @Emma: yes - SQL Server Compact is **NOT** the usual SQL Server. And as I said in my answer - you need specific **tools** for that - see my link!